# When to use this keyword or an event argument?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("span").on("click",function(event){

  event.stopPropagation();

})
```

---

```
$("span").on("click",function(event){

  $(this).stopPropagation();

})
```

---

what is the difference between them, and why is only of them working?

Answer (score 1):

The [`stopPropagation` method only exists on the `Event` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation), that's why your first example works.

On the other hand, `$(this)` is a jQuery  object and not an `Event` object, so your second example does not work.